# how to calculate pixels in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dc.leaflet.js

I am working with leaflet plugins, calculating distance between two points of a polyline or whole distance of joint/multiple lines

**Work :**
I set up the script to measure the distance in meters when using image as map...

**Script**

```
function showPolygonArea(e) {
    featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
    var tempLatLng = null;
    var totalDistance = 0.00000;
    $.each(e.layer._latlngs, function (i, latlng) {
        if (tempLatLng == null) {
            tempLatLng = latlng;
            return;
        }

        //transformation experiment

        totalDistance += tempLatLng.distanceTo(latlng);
        tempLatLng = latlng;
        userDistanceVal = totalDistance / 100000;
    });
    e.layer.bindPopup((totalDistance / 100000).toFixed(2) + ' meters');
    e.layer.openPopup();
}
```

**Problem :**

> here (1) i want to return the totalDistance in pixels instead of
>   meters ....
>
> (2)and here, how can i use layerPoint or containerPoint functin? (as i
>   am struggling about the usage understanding)

I have so little experience in javascript, if doing or asking something stupid, please ignore...
If its possible to do that way, please help....

Any kind of reference or help will be appreciated..thanks for your time

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your problem..
To (1): You can use something like `map.crs.latLngToPoint(latlng, map.getZoom());` to get the pixel-point representation of `latlng`-point at current zoom level. Don't understand the second question, sorry.

Comment: @Krxldfx thanks for reply, i have solved the problem using this method two days ago, please post your comment as answer ..... 2- i was asking about how to use the layerPoint or containerPoint functins(these function suppose to calculate the points, i.e pixels of map container)..... appreciate your effort.... cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To (1): You can use something like `map.crs.latLngToPoint(latlng, map.getZoom());` to get the pixel-point representation of `latlng`-point at current zoom level.